# Javascript hide show object

Tags: javascript, html

This code doesn't work, why?

```
<script>
function color(color_type){
    if (color_type == 'blue'){
        document.getElementById('blue').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'none';
    } 
    else{
        document.getElementById('blue').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>

<select onchange="color(this.value)">
    <option name="choice1" value="red" >red</option>
    <option name="choice2" value="blue" >blue</option>
</select>

<div id="red" style="display:none;">
   <?
   //
   echo "<tr>
<td width='100' class='tbl'>Just ask</td>
<td width='80%' class='tbl'><input type='text' name='1' value='$n1' class='textbox' style='width: 250px'></td>
</tr>";
   //
   ?>
</div>

<div id="blue" style="display:none;">
      <?
   //
   echo "<tr>
<td width='100' class='tbl'>Just ask blue</td>
<td width='80%' class='tbl'><input type='text' name='2' value='$n2' class='textbox' style='width: 250px'></td>
</tr>";
   //
   ?>
</div>
```

Td table doesn't hidden, every time show this table. I need that when I chose blue or red show only "Just ask blue" or "Just ask" table.

P.S sorry for my bad english language

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/nTczy/. Note that `tr` elements **must** be children of a `table` (`thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`) element, they cannot be children of a `div`.

Comment: do you have css for this?

Comment: I have checking this code is working. Please remove caches in your browser.

Comment: It is important to note that you must nest your **tr** tags within a **table** not doing so will cause a lot of unexpected behavior and browser compatibility problems.

Comment: Unless your javascript is wrapped on a window.onload there is no reason for this not to work. Check the browser console, see if you get any erros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your wrapping a div around a  element which is the basis of the table. basicly your html structure is wrong.

```
<div id="red" style="display:none;">
   <?
   //
   echo "<table><tr>
<td width='100' class='tbl'>Just ask</td>
<td width='80%' class='tbl'><input type='text' name='1' value='$n1' class='textbox' style='width: 250px'></td>
</tr></table>";
   //
   ?>
</div>

<div id="blue" style="display:none;">
      <?
   //
   echo "<table><tr>
<td width='100' class='tbl'>Just ask blue</td>
<td width='80%' class='tbl'><input type='text' name='2' value='$n2' class='textbox' style='width: 250px'></td>
</tr></table>";
   //
   ?>
</div>
```

Have a look at the basic structure of a HTML table

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: @James. Upped you one for the catching the bad HTML... I missed that missing table tag!

Answer (score 1):

First, the HTML. Pass your function the select object, but determine the selected value
from within the javascript function and not the HTML. Simplify your select as shown below.
The additional id attribute is not required for it to work, it's just good programming practices these days to provide a reference you can use.

```
<select id="color_choice" onchange="color(this)">
    <option name="choice1" value="red" >red</option>
    <option name="choice2" value="blue" >blue</option>
</select>
```

Now you can determine the value of the select using javascript.
With your example, the change would be as shown below

```
function color( choices ){

    var color_type = choices.options[ choices.selectedIndex ].value;

    if ( color_type == 'blue' ){
        document.getElementById('blue').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'none';
    } 
    else{
        document.getElementById('blue').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have generated invalid HTML.  You can't wrap TABLE elements in DIV elements, since it does not conform to HTML standards (or any HTML compliance for that matter).  If you want to hide rows, assign the ID's to the TR elements and lose the DIV's:

```
<?
//
echo "<tr id='blue' style='display:none;'>
    <td width='100' class='tbl'>Just ask</td>
    <td width='80%' class='tbl'><input type='text' name='1' value='$n1' class='textbox' style='width: 250px'></td>
</tr>";
//
?>
```